# How do I get the file name not the full directory?

Tags: c#, file, filenames

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(openDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open);

        fileLabel.Text = openDialog.FileName;

        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(fileStream);

        // already doing some reading and printing (already got code)

    }
}
```

So the `fileLabel` would change to the full directory with name. How do I set the label as just the name of the file?

Comment: @zerkms It doesn't give the answer to this sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All path related operations can be found in the `System.IO.Path` class.

The one you are looking for is `GetFileName`. Usage:

```
Path.GetFileName( openDialog.FileName );
```

This function separates the very last part from the path string it is supplied with. Note, that if no the path is not pointing to any file, the method returns empty string.

For more details refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `Path.GetFileName()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try -->

```
fileLabel.Text = openDialog.SafeFileName;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`openDialog.SafeFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). According to MSDN: *Gets the file name and extension for the file selected in the dialog box. The file name does not include the path.*